# What does "bore" mean in "Athena's aegis bore the severed head of the monstrous Medusa"?

Tags: meaning

What does "bore" mean in *Athena's aegis bore the severed head of the monstrous Medusa*? I looked it up in dictionaries and found a relevant meaning:

> to make a long deep hole with a tool or by digging

But this seems can't be applied here, as it basically is digging holes. How can one dig a hole on the aegis and the hole looks like Medusa's head? To me the *bore* here means more like "carve", but I can't find this in the dictionary. So what does it really mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this sentence, **bore** is the simple past of **bear**. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bear), **bear** has several meanings- in this sentence, the most likely is

> to have or continue to have something

What this sentance means is that Athena wears an aegis (a protective animal skin) which has a likeness of a medusa's head on it. Here is a statue of Athena: note the gorgon's head featured on the aegis which is worn diagonally across her chest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is the past tense form of "bear", that is, "to carry".